# Is it possible to have different custom validation error message fields for your nested form fields and the global error messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

Running Rails 3.2.x with the [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) gem, I have the usual error messages with ActiveRecord validations in the model such as:

```
class SomeModel
  validates :time, :presence => true, :format => { :with => /[0-9]?[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/ }
end
```

It results in the following (the text in blue in the pictures is just descriptive text made with a photo editor to tell you waht's going on).

**What I'd like to do**

1)  Display a custom message of my choosing such as "This model has blank fields" without the usual Rails predicate.  If try using the **:message** options in the **validates** helper, I end up with an error message saying something like "SomeModel is This model has blank fields".  Basically, it appends the custom message to the model name.  How do I only display my custom message up top?

2)  Display a custom error message for the nested form input field(s) that is different from the custom error message up top of the page.  How do I display a different custom message such as "This is the error message for the nested input field" generated by the nested_form input field?

**Errors at the top of the page**

[image]

**Error messages near the nested_form fields**

[image]